# how to do cancel requests in GCD without operation queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, grand-central-dispatch

I'm implementing an iOS app which make requests using REST service. And I want to cancel all the previous REST calls when I make a new call. Can I do it in the global queue in GCD without Operation Queue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCD does not provide an API to cancel blocks. So you will have to implement this cancellation yourself.

The easiest way probably would be to set a global flag 'canceled' and check that inside of your blocks. If the flag is set, immediately return from your block. Then after all blocks have finished you can reset the flag and enqueue your new block.

Even though that sounds simple, this requires some nontrivial code. It would be much easier to use NSOperationQueue instead of reimplementing its features on top of plain GCD.

Comment: _NSOperationQueue_ is underrated, especially since _NSBlockOperation_ was added

Comment: GCD _has_ an API to cancel blocks: `dispatch_block_cancel()`   (available since OS X 10.10). That alone does not solve the OPs problem, though.

Comment: @nielsbot Unfortunately, `NSBlockOperation` yields operations which cannot be cancelled. :(

Comment: oh yeah--you'd have to make your own subclass of operation then.